# email notification with cell values from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a Google sheet to enter new employees with their first name, last name, title, and dept, and then generate an email to various people with that info when new employees are added.

I've created this code to trigger an email upon editing of the last cell in the row (dept), and I want to generate an email that will include the values of the first two cells (first name, last name) in the subject and all 4 cells (first, last, title, dept) in the body.

But something's not quite right, I'm getting an 'undefined' error for the Rowdata.  Any suggestions?

```
function sendNotificationNEWpersons() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
//Get Active cell
  var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
  var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
  var rowData = sheet.getRange(cellrow, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
//Defined Notification Details
  var recipients = "xxxx@gmail.com";
  var subject = "NEW EMPLOYEE: " + rowData[0][4] + rowData[0][5] + "(Row " + mycell.getRow() + ")";
  var body = rowData[4] + rowData[5] + "has just been added to the NewPersons sheet on Row " + mycell.getRow() + " To view them, visit: " + ss.getUrl();
//If column 5 isn't empty in NewPersons sheet
  if (cellcol == 5 && sheet.getName() == "NewPersons" && mycell.getValue() !=-1)
  {
//Send the Email
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
//End sendNotification
  }
```

Comment: Could you check this line "var rowData = sheet.getRange(cellrow, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();", its wrong. use Logger.log(rowData) and see what you are getting in there... I think that the code should be "var rowData = sheet.getRange(Row, Column, NumberOfRows, NumberOfCoulmns).getValues();"

Answer (score 2):

So you have a few mistakes in your code above that are causing the undefined errors.  Firstly, you are populating rowData with only the contents of a single cell, rather than the whole row as you probably intended.  Secondly, in you are mishandling that rowData variable when setting the values of your subject and body variables.

Assuming that your row data is being placed in Columns A-D of the spreadsheet and the rowData variable is only supposed to contain a single row with 4 columns (corresponding to first name, last name, title and department in that order), here is a fixed version of your code:

```
function sendNotificationNEWpersons() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
  var cellrow = mycell.getRow();

  // Get the full row of data, not just one cell
  var rowData = sheet.getSheetValues(cellrow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  // rowData is now a 2D array of Object (cell values), with a single row
  // and sheet.getLastColumn() columns

  // Here, only including the first and last names in the email
  var recipients = "xxxx@gmail.com";
  var subject = "NEW EMPLOYEE: " + rowData[0][0] + " " + rowData[0][1] +
      "(Row " + mycell.getRow() + ")";
  var body = rowData[0][0] + " " + rowData[0][1] + 
      "has just been added to the NewPersons sheet on Row " + 
      mycell.getRow() + " To view them, visit: " + ss.getUrl();

  //If column 5 isn't empty in NewPersons sheet
  if (cellcol == 5 && sheet.getName() == "NewPersons" &&
      mycell.getValue() !=-1) {
    //Send the Email
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
  }
}
```

The code will avoid the errors you are seeing. However, this solution is probably not the best design. You don't specify how you are calling this function (you could be using a menu control or an onEdit trigger or another function) -- depending on that the assumption that the cell currently selected is on the newest person's row and is sitting in column 5 may not be correct.

Here are some other designs you may want to consider instead:

1. **Use a Google Form**. You can create a Form with (first name, last name, title, department) text fields. Then you can give that form an onFormSubmit(e) trigger to email your recipients whenever a new entry is submitted (the [form submit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events) contains all the data entered into the form). From that point on, new employees can be entered directly into form and that data will be placed in the form responses spreadsheet; the trigger will handle the emails.
2. **Create a sidebar**. You can design a sidebar for the spreadsheet that a user can enter employ data into and include a 'Add employee' button to write that data to the spreadsheet, send out emails and do whatever else that needs doing. This approach is effectively the same as using a Google Form, but is more customizable and more technically challenging. You can examine the [Build an Add-on Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs) for example code on how to construct a working sidebar.
3. **Use [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) triggers correctly**. If you set up a spreadsheet onEdit(e) trigger, you can query the event to determine what cell was edited. You can use that information to determine what row and column you are in without resorting to ss.getActiveSelection(). Note that this approach is not ideal in that onEdit(e) will fire anytime any cell in the spreadsheet is edited, so it requires that you carefully verify the edited cell location is appropriate before the rest of the trigger is executed.